# Integer solutions of a quadratic form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, quadratic-forms

In some cases, it is easy to solve the question of determining the integers representable by à quadratic form. Typically, for forms of the shape $ax^2+by^2=c$, it is pretty straightforward as soon as the coefficients are positive, since there are only finitely many checks to do.

Is there a general method (at least in some cases) to solve such quadratic equations in integers?

I know there are powerful methods using Hensel lemma and Hasse principle, or analytic tools like modular forms, to answer (maybe part of) this question. Are there more Arithmetic/elementary way to approach it?

Comment: Asked and answered many times on this website – have a look around.

Answer (score 1):

Equation: $[ax^2+by^2=c]$

Above has solution shown below,

$x=2qb+p(a-b)$

$y=2ap-q(a-b)$

$c=(a+b)^2(ap^2+bq^2)$

where $(p,q)$ are parameters,

for, $(a,b,p,q)=(7,5,3,2)$ we get after removing common factors,

$(x,y,c)=(13,19,2988)$

Comment: You are taking $c$ to be one of the unknowns, where I would have assumed it was one of the givens.

Comment: If c is considered to be an unknown, x and y are merely any integer and c is constrained to the integers by the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

On the internet there are solutions for $(a,b)=(1,1)$ given by:

$x=2 (m^2+7m+1)$

$y=(11m^2+2m-4)$

$c=5(5m^2+2m+2)^2$

$(a,b,m)=(1,1,2)$

$(x,y,c)=(19,22,845)$

@ Gerry Myerson inquired about the status of 'c'. RHS of equation given by 'OP' is an integer representation. So any variables $(x,y)$ used in the LHS will add up to become an integer. Basically 'c' is not a unknown but becomes a given by virtue of $(a,b,x,y) $. If 'c' is chosen arbitrarily by 'OP' than there might not be a solution to the given equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. An answer is supposed to answer the question, instead just saying that, on the Internet, one can find the answer to a particular case of the question.

Comment: I take the question to be, how do you find all pairs $x,y$ satisfying something like $x^2-2y^2=49$? So, you're given $a,b,c$ and asked to find all $x,y$. Maybe that's not what OP means, but it's what OP *should* mean, because that's the interesting question in this area.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson. Parametric solution to x^2-2y^2=c is (x,y,c)=((3p-4q), (2p-3q), (p^2-2q^2)). Since 'c' is fixed at c=49 only one integer solution (p,q)=(21,14)  & (×,y)=(7,0)  is possible. Instead many rational solution's are possible.

Comment: No, Robert, there are infinitely many solutions in integers to $x^2-2y^2=49. For example, $x=9$, $y=4$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. Regarding my comment on equation (x^2-by^2=c.),  (where b=2). I meant that my parametrization for this equation has one solution. While this equation has the potential for having many different parametrization, finding a (genera)l parametric solution is difficult. Considering that very few diopantine equation's have a general solution. You are right that (x,y)=(9,4) is another solution,  but proving that the equation has infinite solutions is not going to be easy.

Comment: Proving that $x^2-2y^2=49$ has infinitely many solutions in integers $x,y$ is actually very easy, Robert, and the tools are in every introductory number theory text.

Answer (score 0):

The terms of your question are a bit too vague. As I interpret it, you start with a quadratic form $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$, with $a,b \in \mathbf Z$ and look for the integers $c$ which are represented by $f$, i.e. such that $f(x,y)=c$. Classical interesting examples are the Pell-Fermat equation $x^2-by^2=\pm 1$, or the Fermat equation  $x^2+y^2=p$, where $p$ is a prime. Now what do you mean by an "answer to the question" ?

Concerning the Fermat equation, you noticed that, if the form *f* has positive coefficients, *"there are only finitely many [numerical] checks to do."* But what is the interest ? You can check by hand that *p*=2, 5, 13, 17... can be represented and, before going on experimentally forever, conjecture - as Fermat showed - that an odd $p$ is representable by the form  $x^2+y^2$ iff $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$. As for the Pell-Fermat equation, you know that not only does it always have solutions, but these are generated, in a certain precise way, by "minimal"ones, so that any numerical experimentation would be silly.

To follow your trend, let us come back to Fermat, who also stated that $p$ is represented by $x^2+2y^2$ (resp. $x^2+3y^2$) iff $p\equiv 1,3$ mod $8$ (resp. $p=3$ or $p\equiv 2,3$ mod $8$). It is in trying to prove Fermat's assertions that Euler discovered the phenomenon of quadratic reciprocity and formulated conjectures which ultimately culminated in Gauss'proof of the quadratic (and some higher) reciprocity laws and their connection with genera of quadratic forms. The subsequent problem of characterising the primes $p$ of the form $x^2+ny^2, n\in \mathbf N$, was only solved much later by using such formidable tools of the 20th century as class-field theory (CFT) and the theory of complex multiplication ("explicit" CFT over imaginary quadratic fields). See e.g. the marvelous book "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$" by David Cox. (*)

What is my point ? Since Matiyasevich and others have given a negative answer to Hilbert's tenth problem (asking for a *general* algorithm to decide whether a given polynomial Diophantine equation with integer coefficients has a solution in integers), we know, roughly speaking, that any diophantine question with many enough variables and high enough degree could possibly require a *sui generis* solution. To your question about binary quadratic forms:  *Is there a general method (at least in some cases) to solve quadratic equations in integers?*,  I don't know a general answer, but the problem treated in Cox's book suggests a preliminary requirement: *Is the special equation under study interesting enough to be worth developping a specific approach?*

(*)**NB.**   You write that *there are powerful methods using Hensel lemma and Hasse principle, or analytic tools like modular forms, to answer (maybe part of) [your] question.* But note that Hasse's principle is a "local-global" approach (Hensel's lemma is local) which applies only to *rational* quadratic forms (as opposed to diophantine). As for the special modular forms used e.g. by Cox, they belong the complex multiplication.

Comment: I don't think the Matiyasevich result applies to quadratics in two unknowns. I think you need more unknowns and/or higher degree to get algorithmic undecidability.

Comment: True. I edit this to avoid confusion.